# Django and selenium TypeError: setUpClass() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'

Tags: django, python-3.x, selenium

I'am trying to experiment django v2 with selenium and got this error:

```html
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (level.tests.LevelListViewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: setUpClass() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

This is how my test looks like:

```python
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver


class LevelListViewTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @staticmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(10)

    @staticmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        cls.selenium.tearDownClass()

    def test_level_is_in_admin_panel(self):
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/admin/login/?next=/admin/'))
```

I use sqlite as database and I have already created a superuser and installed selenium using pip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want the @classmethod decorator on your setup and teardown functions, @staticmethod is for instances.

Answer (score 0):

These should use the `@classmethod` decorator, not `@staticmethod`.